# How to perform a post hoc test for a mixed model in beta distribution (I am using R's gamlss library)?

Tags: r, mixed-models, posthoc, beta-distribution, gamlss

How do I perform a post hoc test for a random effect beta distribution?

To build the mixed model with beta distribution I used the library gamlss  (I found no other way to do this in R). In this model there is a factor with three levels. Suppose level1, level2 and level3. The summary shows the comparison between level1 x level2 and level1 x level3, since level1 is the baseline.

library(gamlss)
mymodel <- gamlss(response~ph+dose, family = BE, random=~1|id, data = mydata)
summary(mymodel)

It shows the comparison between level1 x level2 and level1 x level3

For all three levels, the summary shows the comparison between level1 x level2 and level1 x level3, as level1 is the baseline.

I would like to test if there is difference between level2 x level3. How can I do this? Maybe there could be another library for this. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

**emmeans** doesn't yet work for gamlss objects

you can try  **mgcv::anova.gam(model)** which will print a summary for you but the output list is  cranky to work with and cannot easily be converted to a data frame.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to have a look at the package "emmeans".

```
    library("emmeans")
    Post_Hoc <- emmeans (model, specs = pairwise ~ Var, type = "response")
    summary(Post_Hoc)
```

Good luck

Tibo